# Weird save to array in foreach in php

Tags: php, printing, foreach

Something strange happens during saving into an array inside a **foreach**.

I'm getting unexpected results so I make this part of code for debuging.

```
$search_case = new stdClass();
$same_case = array ();
print_r($families);

foreach ($families as $key => $family) {
    echo "<br/><br/>";
    $same_case['aaaaa'.$key] = $this->search_benef->search_case($family, $search_case);
    print_r($same_case);
}
```

The problem is that when I get function's results for $key = 1 it also change the data in table for $key = 0. To chek that I created aaaaa0 and aaaaa1 names for my table.

Bellow is **print_r** results:

**First print_r** I have 2 objects, IBRAHIM and MOHAMMAD

stdClass Object ( **[0]** => stdClass Object ( [focal] => stdClass Object ( [name] => RENAS [surname] => IBRAHIM [case_number] => 36343 ) [case] => 36343 ) **[1]** => stdClass Object ( [focal] => stdClass Object ( [name] => AZAD [surname] => MOHAMMAD [case_number] => 54944 ) [case] => 54944 ) )

**Second print_r** inside foreach loop, in the first loop I get results for IBRAHIM and in the second loop Ι get results for MOHAMMAD, but it removes results for IBRAHIM in aaaaa0.

Array ( **[aaaaa0]** => stdClass Object ( [old] => stdClass Object ( [hotel] => stdClass Object ( [focal] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 26 [name] => RENAS [surname] => IBRAHIM ) ) ) ) )

Array ( **[aaaaa0]** => stdClass Object ( [old] => stdClass Object ( [hotel] => stdClass Object ( [focal] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 22 [name] => AZAD [surname] => MOHAMMAD ) ) [athens] => stdClass Object ( [focal] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 24 [name] => AZAD [surname] => MOHAMMAD ) ) ) ) **[aaaaa1]** => stdClass Object ( [old] => stdClass Object ( [hotel] => stdClass Object ( [focal] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 22 [name] => AZAD [surname] => MOHAMMAD ) ) [athens] => stdClass Object ( [focal] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 24 [name] => AZAD [surname] => MOHAMMAD ) ) ) ) )

Can you explain why this happens? Which is the error?

**-- EDIT --**

I change my code and I remove 'search_case' function, but I face the same problem. The content changes. Below I paste my new code without the function.

```
    $aaaaa = array ();

    foreach ($families as $key => $family) {
        echo "<br/><br/>Family->Case Number: " . $family->case;
        $db_lists = array('athens' => 'athensDB', 'hotel' => 'hotelDB');

        foreach ($db_lists as $key => $db_list) {
            $remoteDB = $this->ci->load->database($key, TRUE);

            $query = 'SELECT  tb.id as id, name, surname FROM beneficiaries tb
                left join _map_family_status tmfs ON tmfs.id=tb.family_status
                where asylum_case = ' . $family->case . ' AND family_status = 1 GROUP BY asylum_case';

            $focal = $remoteDB->query($query)->row();

            if ($focal) {
                $search_case->old->$key->focal = $focal;
            }
        }
        echo '<br/> '.$family->case.' <br/> ';

        $aaaaa[$family->case] = $search_case;
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($aaaaa);
        echo "</pre>";

    }
    return $aaaaa;
```

But the results are dissapointing. Array[36343] content changes with the second loop's content. Below I paste "print_r" results for the two loops.

```
Family->Case Number: 36343
Array (
    [36343] => stdClass Object (
        [old] => stdClass Object (
            [hotel] => stdClass Object (
                [focal] => stdClass Object (
                    [id] => 26
                    [name] => RENAS
                    [surname] => IBRAHIM
                )
            )
        )
    )
)


Family->Case Number: 54944
Array (
    [36343] => stdClass Object (
        [old] => stdClass Object (
            [hotel] => stdClass Object (
                [focal] => stdClass Object (
                    [id] => 22
                    [name] => AZAD
                    [surname] => MOHAMMAD
                )
            )
            [athens] => stdClass Object (
                [focal] => stdClass Object (
                    [id] => 24
                    [name] => AZAD
                    [surname] => MOHAMMAD
                )
            )
        )
    )

    [54944] => stdClass Object (
        [old] => stdClass Object (
            [hotel] => stdClass Object (
                [focal] => stdClass Object (
                    [id] => 22
                    [name] => AZAD
                    [surname] => MOHAMMAD
                )
            )
            [athens] => stdClass Object (
                [focal] => stdClass Object (
                    [id] => 24
                    [name] => AZAD
                    [surname] => MOHAMMAD
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: The issue looks like how the variable is declared in the 'search_case' function.  I'm suspecting it's using a reference variable there.  Without seeing the other code, can't definitely answer.

Comment: @Forbs , can you find now the error in my code, that gives me these results?